# How to find complex coordinates of a square?

Tags: complex-numbers

If one coordinate is given by: $z_{1}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{2}i$

and $Re(z_{2})=6,Re(z_{4})=1$.

How to find $z_{2},z_{3},z_{4}$ so that $z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}z_{4}$ forms a square in the first quadrant?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Use rotation theorem. I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_2=6+ai$, $z_3=b+ci$,$z_4=1+di$.

We have $Z_4=rot_{Z_1}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(Z_2)$, so $z_4-z_1=(cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{2} )(z_2-z_1)=iz_2-iz_1$, so $(1-\frac{3}{2})+i(d-\frac{3}{2})=(-a+\frac{3}{2})+i(6-\frac{3}{2})$. Then: $a=2$ and $d=6$.

Now, $Z_1=rot_{Z_2}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(Z_3)$, so $z_1-z_2=(cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{2} )(z_3-z_2)=iz_3-iz_2$, or $(\frac{3}{2}-6)+i(\frac{3}{2}-2)=(2-c)+i(b-6)$; then $c=\frac{13}{2}$ and $b=\frac{11}{2}$.

Comment: How did you get the expressions for $z_{4}$ and $z_{3}$?

Comment: What expressions?

Comment: $z_{1}=rot(z_{3}),z_{4}=rot(z_{2})$. Can Moivre's theorem be used on this problem?

Comment: Try to draw the square and you should uderstand! I don't think that Moivre's theorem can be used in this problem!